# Does the Reward of Repentance in Jeremiah 18:8 refer to spiritual salvation (in Heaven) or homeland security (on Earth)?

Tags: prophecy, authorial-intent, jeremiah, soteriology

**The Word of YHVH דְבַר יְהֹוָ֖ה is spoken through the prophet Yirmiyahu יִרְמְיָ֔הוּ regarding the conditional reward for national repentance** :

> [Yirmiyahu יִרְמְיָ֔הוּ “Jeremiah” 18:8, MT]
> “And when that nation repents of its evil for which I spoke concerning it, I will repent of the evil that I thought to do to it.” ( וְשָׁב֙ הַגּ֣וֹי הַה֔וּא מֵרָ֣עָת֔וֹ אֲשֶׁ֥ר דִּבַּ֖רְתִּי עָלָ֑יו וְנִֽחַמְתִּי֙ עַל־הָ֣רָעָ֔ה אֲשֶׁ֥ר חָשַׁ֖בְתִּי לַֽעֲשׂ֥וֹת לֽוֹ )

> [Jeremiah 18:8, KJV]
> “If that nation, against whom I have pronounced, turn from their evil, I will repent of the evil that I thought to do unto them.”

- [Question] **Does the Reward of Repentance in Jeremiah 18:8 refer to spiritual salvation (in Heaven) or homeland security (on Earth)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeremiah 18:8, KJV

> “If that **nation**, against whom I have pronounced, turn from their evil, I will repent of the evil that I thought to do unto them.”

Does the Reward of Repentance in Jeremiah 18:8 refer to spiritual salvation (in Heaven) or homeland security (on Earth)?

The target of that verse was a nation. It was talking about homeland security (on Earth). There was no such thing as wholesale spiritual salvation (in Heaven) for an entire physical nation.

An application of this verse is found in the story of Jonah. The Ninevites repented upon the preaching of Jonah.

Jonah 3:

> 10 When God saw what they did and how they turned from their evil ways, he relented and did not bring on them the destruction he had threatened.

Answer (score 1):

**Does the Reward of Repentance in Jeremiah 18:8 refer to spiritual salvation (in Heaven) or homeland security (on Earth)?**

Homeland security:

God forgives those that practiced wickedness, but later have a change of heart. When God observes that those sinning turn their lives around and obey him, he comes to feel regret: In what way?

> [Jeremiah 18:8, KJV] “If that nation, against whom I have pronounced,
> turn from their evil, I will repent of the evil that I thought to do
> unto them.”

Jeremiah 26:3 NASB

> 3 Perhaps they will listen and everyone will turn from his evil way,
> and I will relent of the disaster which I am planning to inflict on
> them because of the evil of their deeds.’